# SciPy sparse matrix ".multiply" not returning expected results?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

So I have a COO matrix "coo_mat" created using scipy.sparse, with the first three non-zero elements being:

```
coo_mat.data[:5]
>>> array([0.61992174, 1.30911574, 1.48995508])
```

I wish to multiply the matrix by 2, and I understand that I can simply do:

```
(coo_mat*2).data[:5]
>>> array([1.23984347, 2.61823147, 2.97991015])
```

However, I don't understand why the results are not consistent when I try:

```
coo_mat.multiply(2).data[:5]
>>> array([2.04156392, 1.54042948, 2.3306947 ])
```

I've used the element-wise multiplication method in other analyses and it was working as I expected. Is there something I missing when using `sparse.coo_matrix.multiply()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SciPy doesn't promise anything about the output format of most sparse matrix operations. It can reorder the elements of a COO matrix, or even switch formats to CSR or CSC or something. Here, `coo_mat.multiply(2)` is returning a CSR matrix with a completely different element representation and element layout:

```
In [11]: x = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix([[1]])

In [12]: type(x.multiply(2))
Out[12]: scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

`scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` [inherits](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/sparse/base.py#L337) its `multiply` method from the `scipy.sparse.spmatrix` base class, which implements `multiply` as

```
def multiply(self, other):
    """Point-wise multiplication by another matrix
    """
    return self.tocsr().multiply(other)
```

There's no optimization for COO in that method.

Comment: Okay, but when I converted the CSR matrix back to COO using both `.tocoo()` and `sparse.coo_matrix()` and inspected the first 3 elements, I do not obtain the expected values. I understand how the different sparse matrices are organizing and storing the non-zero elements, but the dense matrix should be consistent.

Comment: @bz13531: Look at the `toarray` output, then, not the `data`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the order of the non-zero elements in `.data` were resorted after being converted to CSR. I've confirmed this by checking `.row` and `.col` of the COO matrix before and after `.multiply()`.

Comment: Nonzeros in a COO can be in any order.  In a CSR they are always sorted by rows, and usually by column within the rows as well.  Look at the `.has_canonical_format` attribute.